# Windows Server OS versus Windows Desktop OS for a persistent 3D application

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-server-2012, 3d-graphics, unity3d

As part of a project I'm working on, I want to put a Unity3D application on a server, meant to run 24/7. This application simply accepts incoming requests via sockets, renders images (fast rendering has the highest priority) and returns rendered images via sockets.

What OS should I use for this? Linux isn't fully supported by Unity3D yet, so the choice comes down to Windows Server of Windows Desktop.

I don't have a lot of experience with this sort of thing but from my own research I've concluded there's two ways to go about this:

A) Install Windows Server and tinker with it to get 3D acceleration working.

B) Install Windows Desktop and tinker with it to get it faster/more stable.

Which would you recommend? Are there any trade-offs in stability and/or performance to either of these choices?

Comment: If its serving a specific purpose and is going to be on 24/7 I would recommend Server. Depending on the hardware being used there shouldn't be too much tinkering to get £D acceleration working, I'm guessing you'll be using professional 3D cards such as Quadro rather than a gaming card?

Comment: We've determined that high-end gaming cards are sufficient for our needs.

Comment: You might find it trickier to get drivers for the gaming cards than cards such as Quadro's however if you know the specific card model you can check what drivers are supported on Nvidia/ATI website. As your not going to be requiring remote desktop access you will not need to mess about with RemoteFX or anything which can be tricky. I would say if you can get the driver use Windows Server if you cannot get the driver for the card in question then it'll have to be Windows Desktop...

Comment: There are only two things you should really consider in a case like this.  The first will consumer level graphic card meet your rendering requirements.  The second will the hardware limitations ( connected clients, CPU, and memory ) of a consumer level version of Windows meet your requirements.  Of course there is a third concern.  Windows Server isn't cheap.  So if price is a concern you should rule that option out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharlesH pointed out that not all video cards are supported by Windows Server. I was unable to find any Windows Server drivers for the card(s) we intend to use. According to colleagues, Quardo cards and the like (which do have Windows Server drivers) are not fit for our intended purposes. So it seems Windows Desktop is our only option.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be a desktop machine.

At a previous place I worked, we had a real time 3D graph of commits/breaks into a version control server (This is back in 2009) and we quickly found then, that there was a big difference to the stability of 3D graphics on a desktop system as opposed to a server system.

Desktop systems are designed for end users, and end users are expected to want to do things like gaming and fancy graphics, so the graphics subsystems in a desktop build has more safeguards in place to prevent issues occurring.

Many desktop systems are also not designed to be headless, so a lot of the graphics drivers out there will actively monitor their hardware for crashes and overheating, and reload/recover the driver so the user of the system can see what their doing in order to take remedial action.

Server builds on the other hand, are designed to run long periods, often without any kind of display attached, so software to recover a faulting display driver may not be as important, especially since most windows servers have their graphics output layer tuned for access from a workstation using remote desktop.

Lastly, desktop builds have the graphics subsystem removed out of the kernel code, and while this is also largely true of server builds, there is more risk of a graphics driver crash on a server build causing more problems that require a machine re-boot than there is on a desktop build.

The one problem you might find with a desktop build however is accumulation of crud.  Temporary files building up, windows indexing it's search index etc, and yes dare I say it desktop builds do need to be rebooted at least occasionally.

That said, my office PC (A 64 bit windows 7 machine) get's left on pretty much 24/7, and it's in constant heavy use, but I usually get away with manually doing a controlled re-boot about once a month.

If there's no other activity on the system and only your 3D application running, and as long as you turn off non essential services such as windows search, then you should be ok.

Implement a manual policy to reboot the thing once a month to install updates and such like and you should be fine.

As for network performance, well again on my office PC I have a number of IIS7 sites that I use for monitoring my other machines, many of these I access remotely from things like my laptop, and it all works perfectly fine for internal tools that have at most 100 users.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question, can you explain?

Comment: Yes what's rendered is the same, but if you look at the documentation in the windows C/Asm Device driver kit, along with the samples, you'll see there's a big difference in how desktop & server builds actually handle the device driver.  The device driver is designed from an App perspective be it DX, OGL or Unity to provide a consistent API, that's exactly what windows as an OS provides.  If your talking stability concerns however, especially with a consumer GFX card as the OP is, then a desktop build, from a driver level perspective is the better of the two.

Comment: There is far to much noise for this answer to be very helpful and thus I cannot upvote it.  if/When the answer is acceptable I will upvote it.  I have chosen to delete my comments due the user's unwillingness to improve.

Comment: That's your decision, I'm not asking you to up vote it.  Your a free man, do as you please :-)  There will be others who will find it of interest however, and in time there will be others who will come along and either up or down vote it.  Some people take stack and it's gaming system far to seriously, me I'm just here to help folks.  If you want to improve, then improve, post your own answer, tearing mine apart if that's what you feel you have to do it's a free world.